# azure build pipeline error using resharper task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, resharper, azure-pipelines

I am trying to make an Azure DevOps build pipeline for a .net web app that runs my unit tests, builds the app and then runs Resharper code analysis on the solution and if there are no major issues with code analysis, it will publish an artifact. When I manually run this pipeline I get the following error:

> ##[error]No solution or project found at C:\Users\35385\source\repos\DevOpsCA2\BMICalculator.sln

I am not sure why I am getting this as this is the correct path to the solution.. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

My `.yaml` pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/BMIUnitTestProject/*.csproj'
    arguments:  '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'


- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: ResharperCli@2
  inputs:
    solutionOrProjectPath: 'C:\Users\35385\source\repos\DevOpsCA2\BMICalculator.sln'
    additionalArguments: '--properties:Configuration=$(Build.Configuration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName:  'dotnet publish --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: true
    projects: '**/BMICalculator/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifacts'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [Microsoft hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops) `windows-latest`, it's a new fresh machine, the build is not run on **your** PC, so the solution not exist in this path.

You should specify the path in the agent machine, for example:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirecotry)\DevOpsCA2\BMICalculator.sln
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried solutionOrProjectPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirecotry)\DevOpsCA2\BMICalculator.sln' although I still get this error: ##[error]No solution or project found at d:\a\1\s\$(Build.SourcesDirecotry)\DevOpsCA2\BMICalculator.sln

Comment: solutionOrProjectPath: 'BMICalculator/BMICalculator.csproj' works fine. thanks again for the help Shayki